# how do i transform json values into keys

Tags: json, underscore.js

is there a faster way to transform this:

```
[
    { name: 'name1', value: 'value1' },
    { name: 'name2', value: 'value2' },
    { name: 'name3', value: 'value3' },
    ...
]
```

into this:

```
{
    name1: value1,
    name2: value2,
    name3: value3,
    ...
}
```

without manually looping and filling an object?
could the underscore library have a way to do this? it is already in our application, so
it can be used without an extra cost.

currently i have a manual action,
though i'm not sure it is the best performance i can have.

```
    var data = [];      // see the array above
    var result = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var o = data[i];
        result[o.name] = o.value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a faster way. With underscore there is a shorter way, but it's almost certainly slower than your loop:

```
var result = _.reduce(data, function(r,o) { r[o.name] = o.value; return r; }, {});
```

Comment: i kept the for loop, as it is better performance
and the underscore method did not really make it that mutch shorter anyway. but thanks for giving me the way to do it with underscore. i keep learning new usecases with underscore methods that way!

Comment: Yeah, Underscore's nice. but JS is awfully verbose for that style of programming.  Which I suppose is why there's CoffeScript...